# Удаление строк из таблицы SQL

Tags: sql, строки

Есть таблица с такой структурой

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
-----+------+----- 
 a   |   d  |  t
-----+------+-----
 d   |   t  |  a
-----+------+-----    
 a   |   t  |  d
-----+------+-----
 m   |   n  |  l
-----+------+-----
 l   |   m  |  n
```

Записи, которые могут быть получены из других записей перестановкой значений в столбцах, должны выводиться только один раз. В данном случае ответ будет такой:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
-----+------+-----
 a   |   d  |   t
-----+------+-----
 l   |   m  |   n
```

Необходимо решить задачу при помощи стандартного SQL

Подскажите пож-та с чего начать и как организовать алгоритм

Comment: а еще есть какиенибудь колонки типа индекса уникального?

Comment: 1. Нужен только SQL? 2. Какой SQL? 3. Нафига такой изврат?

Comment: После лабораторной работы препод задал доп задачу. Мы прошли еще только основы sql. Никаких уникальных колонок нет.

Comment: Проверяю работу запроса в oracle sql developer.
Сначала необходимо упорядочить строки в таблице. Затем выбрать не повторяющиеся записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение задачи оказалось намного проще. Может-быть кому-нибудь еще поможет)

```
select distinct least(col1,col2,col3) as col1
                ,greatest(col1,col2,col3) as col2
                ,case when col1 not in (least(col1,col2,col3) ,greatest(col1,col2,col3)) then col1
                 when col2 not in (least(col1,col2,col3) ,greatest(col1,col2,col3)) then col2
                else col3 end col3
from table1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой изврат у меня получился для MS SQL:

```
select distinct max, middle, min
from
(
select 
(select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)) as max
,(
select *
from
(
select (case when col1 not in((select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)),(select MIN(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v))) then col1 end) as m
union
select (case when col2 not in((select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)),(select MIN(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v))) then col2 end) as m
union
select (case when col3 not in((select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)),(select MIN(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v))) then col3 end) as m
) t where m is not null
) as middle
,(select MIN(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)) as min
from #t
) temp
```

Где #t исходная таблица.

Comment: DISTINCT необходимо применять только к max?

Comment: distinct в данном контексте применится ко всем полям

Comment: можно пояснить для чего здесь используются слова values и что обозначает MAX(v)?

Comment: Кратко на примере

    select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)

в секции from мы используем конструктор табличных значений (values (col1), (col2), (col3)), затем мы должны как-то проименовать созданную таблицу - в примере я ее назвал value, в скобках мы указываем названия столбцов - т.е. v. Ну и в селекте берем максимум по столбцу v.

Comment: В oracle sql developer монжно такой конструктор использовать? Есть еще способы сортировки значений в строке?

Comment: Насчет oracle sql developer - не знаю. Вставьте код и попробуйте выполнить - ответ будет однозначный) Насчет сортировки значений в строке (насколько я понял здесь речь идет о вот этом куске кода select MAX(v) from (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) as value(v)) - насколько я знаю в MS SQL-е таких функций нет, т.е. только вот такие самописные.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что у меня получилось - не совсем верно

```
SELECT DISTINCT max, midl, small
FROM (
SELECT  least(COL1, COL2, CoL3) as max,replace(replace(CONCAT(COL1, COL2, CoL3),greatest(COL1, COL2, CoL3),''),least(COL1, COL2, CoL3),'') as midl, greatest(COL1, COL2, CoL3) as small
FROM test) as t1
```

Если есть уникальная колонка (id)
Вот запрос

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COl3
FROM (
SELECT id, least( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) AS max, replace( replace( CONCAT( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , greatest( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , '' ) , least( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , '' ) AS midl, greatest( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) AS small
FROM test
) AS t1, test
WHERE test.id = t1.id
GROUP BY max, midl, small
```

А вот, если колонок больше нет - правильный запрос

```
SELECT test.COL1, test.COL2, test.COL3
FROM (
SELECT COL1, least( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) AS max, replace( replace( CONCAT( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , greatest( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , '' ) , least( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) , '' ) AS midl, greatest( COL1, COL2, CoL3 ) AS small
FROM test
) AS t1, test
WHERE test.COL1 = t1.COL1
GROUP BY max, midl, small
```

Comment: что такое least(), replace() и greatest()? Это функции?

Comment: дф функции SQL)

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм такой:

1. Упорядочить значения в столбцах [CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html)ами.
2. Использовать DISTINCT.